# How to add function to a button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add a function where when I press a button, text shows up somewhere on a screen.
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'App';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatelessWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text('Text Button'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 30),
          OutlinedButton(
            style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
              textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text('Outlined Button'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 30),
          ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text('Contained Button'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 30),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So, what is the **question**? What happens when you try using the code? How is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0):

call `changeText` method in the button click

```
String _label = "Text";
  int count = 0 ;

  void changeText(){
    setState(() {
      _label = "Count $count" ;
    });
  }


      ElevatedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
        changeText() // this function
        },
        child: const Text('Contained Button'),
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `StatelessWidget`  to `StatefulWidget`

Then Initialize in the top a string value like below:

```
String test = '';
```

Then Above your elevated button or anywhere in your screen Initialize a text widget like below with the test value:

```
     Text(test),
```

Then in one of your buttons setSate to change the value of the string test:

```
 TextButton(
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            test = 'hello wolrd';
          });
        },
        child: const Text('Text Button'),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

you should recognize between `StatelessWidget` and `StatefulWidget`

`StatelessWidget`Only updates when it is initialized but `StatefulWidget` Changes dynamically if you are using Android studio or Vscode or Intellij then it is easy to change between them just click on `StatelessWidget` and then change it

you can create  `_showText` function and call it in your buttton
here is the full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'App';

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: MyApp._title,
      home: MyWidget()
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
String testText="";

   _showText(){
    setState(() {
      testText= "Show my Text";

    });
      
    }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("$testText"),
          TextButton(
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              _showText();
            },
            child: const Text('Text Button'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 30),
          OutlinedButton(
            style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
              textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text('Outlined Button'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 30),
          ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text('Contained Button'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 30),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```